# How can I painlessly merge divergent feature branches?

Tags: git

I have an open PR on a branch called `feature-b` that will soon be merged to `main`. However, I wrote it to support my `feature-a` branch, which is ongoing. I want to continue working on `feature-a` and leverage the work I did in `feature-b` *before it has been merged to `main`*.

What is the best way for me to do this? Our merges to `main` are squashed, so all commits on `feature-b` will be rewritten as a single commit when it is merged to `main`. Therefore, rebasing `feature-a` on `feature-b` now will result in future conflict pain when I merge `feature-a` to `main` because the same changes will have been made in different commits.

What is the best way for me to include the changes made in `feature-b` in my `feature-a` branch whilst minimizing future pain when I eventually merge `feature-a` to `main`?

### UPDATE

I went ahead and:

1. Rebased `feature-a` on `feature-b`
2. Made more changes (only 1 commit) to `feature-a` whilst `feature-b` was being reviewed
3. Squash-merged `feature-b` once it was approved (no further changes required, so `feature-a` already has the exact code that was merged)
4. Pulled latest `main` and rebased `feature-a` on top of it

As feared, git complains that several files are "both modified" or "both added". This alone would be a little annoying, but simple to fix. What makes it incredibly confusing - especially if any passage of time has passed - is the merge comments in the files.

Even though both `main` and `feature-a` branches have the *exact same code* in all files, I get super annoying behavior:

1. For the "both added" files, merge comments are added for "HEAD (Current Change)" and "parent of #HASH (commit message)". I am forced to choose one or the other, even though they are exactly the same!
2. For the "both modified" files, it is even worse. The "HEAD (Current Change)" shows the correct code. However, the "parent of #HASH (commit message)" section shows half of the code. Again, *even though both branches have all the code!!* I kid you not, accepting the "incoming change" (as labelled by VS Code) will remove code that is in both branches!

If I had not made these changes in quick succession, I'd be hopelessly lost and confused about what git is showing me. That has indeed happened several times in the past but I couldn't put a finger on what was going wrong. Now that I've reproduced this and verified the behavior, I am completely flummoxed as to what git is doing and how people are dealing with this scenario.

### UPDATE 2

OK, I kind of see why it was going to remove code now. It's because the changes I made in `feature-b` were in multiple commits, and those commits ended up being squashed when the merge to `main` occurred. This is no doubt the source of the pain and why I'm trying to figure out a saner workflow.

Comment: What if you rebase feature-a on main once feature-b is merged in?

Comment: @AlectoIrenePerez That requires waiting for the merge, which is holding up my work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced the final merge/squash will be messy.  If the same change is being made in different commits, maybe Git can detect that and be happy with it.

If you do think it will be messy though, what you could do is:

1. Rebase your `feature-a` branch with `feature-b` now, so that your `feature-a` branch now includes the completed feature B and the in-progress feature A, which is what you need to do your work.
2. After `feature-b` gets merged into the `main` branch, rebase `feature-a` onto the commit immediately *before* the squashed commit that they made for feature B.  This should go smoothly.
3. On your `feature-a` branch, use `git reset --soft X` where `X` is the commit hash for the squashed commit they made for feature B.  Then use `git commit` to make a commit.  Now you have a squashed commit whose contents is equal to the current state of your work on feature A.  But this commit's parent is the commit that added feature B to the main branch, so this commit's diff with that parent will *only* contain feature A.  It is fine to continue working on feature A at this point, or just request a merge.

By the way, I'm pretty confident things would not need to be this messy if your organization used merges instead of rebases to add things to the main branch.  And then there would be the benefit of preserving the actual history of the code you were working on, instead of just preserving this artificial history.

Comment: To be clear, we don't use rebases - we use squashed commits. And I'm 99% sure things _will_ be messy as I've tried this in the past. Git gets horribly confused by distinct commits making the same changes. I'm willing to try it again though and report back :)

Comment: @me-- I'm pretty sure squashed commits is a rebase

Comment: Rebasing means moving the branch so it starts a different point, which rewrites the history of how it was developed.  Squashing means changing the whole branch into just one commit, discarding the history of how it was developed except for the final result.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Please see my updated question for an explanation of the behavior I see from git.

Comment: OK.  Your step 4 ("Pulled latest main and rebased feature-a on top of it") is what caused you all the pain so it's not something I would recommend doing.  Instead of doing that step 4 in your question, try steps 2 and 3 from my answer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidGrayson. It seems so . . . laborious  People really use git like this? Wowser.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, the trouble is caused by the person doing all this reading and squashing instead of simply merging.